# How to get ChangeSet(All files changes) from IWorkItem item by Program

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

How to get ChangeSet(All files changes) from IWorkItem item by Program.

I want a list contains all the files that got change for a RTC. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see if [this thread helps](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109157/why-does-this-code-not-return-any-changesets-for-the-supplied-iworkitem-rtc-40): (from the client side)

- `repository` is an `ITeamRepository`
- `mgr` is an `IItemManager` (`repository.itemManager()`)
- `workItem` is the `IWorkItem` for which we want changesets
- `items` holds the set of associated changeset links for the `workitem`

Code:

```java
IClientLibraryContext ctx = (IClientLibraryContext)repository;
IQueryService svc = (IQueryService)ctx.getServiceInterface(IQueryService.class);
AuditableLinkQueryModel alqr = AuditableLinkQueryModel.ROOT;
IItemQuery iq = IItemQuery.FACTORY.newInstance(alqr);

iq.filter(alqr.name()._eq("com.ibm.team.filesystem.workitems.change_set").
  _and( alqr.targetRef().referencedItem().itemId()._eq(iq.newUUIDArg())));

IItemQueryPage itemQueryPage = svc.queryItems(
  iq,
  new Object[] { workItem.getItemId() }, 
  IQueryService.ITEM_QUERY_MAX_PAGE_SIZE);

List<IChangeSet> items = mgr.fetchCompleteItems(itemQueryPage.getItemHandles(), 
                                    mgr.DEFAULT, null);
Set<String> changedFilesAndFolders = new TreeSet<String>();
for (IChangeSet cs: changeSets) {
   ...
}
```

You would still need to list files within each change set of `items`.

you have some idea to list files in:

- "[How to get an `IConfiguration` from `IChangeSet`?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/49910/how-to-get-an-iconfiguration-from-ichangeset)"
- "[how get Full path of the File from changeset Using API?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/93557/how-get-full-path-of-the-file-from-changeset-using-api)"

Other sources:

- "[Setting up Rational Team Concert for API Development](https://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/setting-up-rational-team-concert-for-api-development/)"
- "[The RTC WorkItem Client Link API – Linking to Work Items and Other Elements](https://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/the-rtc-workitem-link-api-linking-workitems-to-other-elements/)"

Comment: Sir, how can I get IItemManager(mgr) ?

Comment: got it : repository.itemManager()

Comment: @VarunGupta Indeed. I have added that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
              private String getChangeSetFiles(IWorkItem workItem, ProjectContext ctx) throws TeamRepositoryException {
    ILinkManager linkManager = (ILinkManager) ctx.repository.getClientLibrary(ILinkManager.class);
    IWorkspaceManager workspaceManager = (IWorkspaceManager)ctx.repository.getClientLibrary(IWorkspaceManager.class);
    IItemReference workItemReference = linkManager.referenceFactory().createReferenceToItem(workItem);
    ILinkCollection linkCollection = linkManager.findLinksByTarget(ILinkConstants.CHANGESET_WORKITEM_LINKTYPE_ID, workItemReference, new SysoutProgressMonitor()).getAllLinksFromHereOn();

    if (linkCollection.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Work item has no change sets.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    List<IChangeSetHandle> changeSetHandles = new ArrayList<IChangeSetHandle>();

    for (ILink link: linkCollection) {
        // Change set links should be item references
        IChangeSetHandle changeSetHandle = (IChangeSetHandle) link.getSourceRef().resolve();

        changeSetHandles.add(changeSetHandle);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<IChangeSet> changeSets = ctx.repository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItems(changeSetHandles, IItemManager.DEFAULT, new SysoutProgressMonitor());
    Set<String> changedFilesAndFolders = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (IChangeSet cs: changeSets) {
        for (Object o: cs.changes()) {
            IChange change = (IChange)o;

            if (change.kind() != IChange.DELETE) {
                IVersionableHandle after = change.afterState();

                // Although versionable handles are item handles you cannot use the item
                //  manager to fetch the versionable from the handle. Instead, you use the
                //  versionable manager to do this.
                IVersionable afterVersionable = workspaceManager.versionableManager().fetchCompleteState(after, new SysoutProgressMonitor());

                changedFilesAndFolders.add(afterVersionable.getName());
            }

            // If there was a rename then include the old name in the list as well
            if (change.kind() == IChange.RENAME
                    || change.kind() == IChange.DELETE) {
                IVersionableHandle before = change.beforeState();

                IVersionable beforeVersionable = workspaceManager.versionableManager().fetchCompleteState(before, new SysoutProgressMonitor());

                changedFilesAndFolders.add(beforeVersionable.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
    for (String fileOrFilderName: changedFilesAndFolders) {
        sb.append(fileOrFilderName+"\n");
        System.out.println("\t"+fileOrFilderName);
    }       
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Got answer from :
https://jazz.net/library/article/1229

Comment: Good feedback. I have completed my answer accordingly.